# Проблемы с gettext

Tags: lua, gettext

При изучении gettext в lua возникла странная проблема: попросту не работает. Структура папок:

```
gtest ->
    locale ->
            ru ->
                    LC_MESSAGES ->
                                    test.mo
                                    test.po
    test.lua
```

Код, который это грузит:

```
gettext = require 'gettext' --> библиотека https://github.com/bungle/lua-resty-gettext/blob/master/lib/resty/gettext.lua
gettext.bindtextdomain ('test', 'locale');
gettext.textdomain ('test');
_ = gettext.gettext
```

Однако, перевод не отображается. В чём дело?
UPD: LANG = ru_RU.UTF8 .

Comment: А как переводите, что в test.po и как получили test.mo?

Comment: test.po: https://paste.ubuntu.com/17426690/, test.mo -- с помощью msgfmt test.po.

Comment: А если `export LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8` в консоли и потом запустить программу в той же консоли?

Comment: @andreymal и так задана такой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед определением домена необходимо выполнить

```
os.setlocale ('');
```

Если вы хотите поменять язык, то вам нужен такой код (перед `setlocale`):

```
ffi = require 'ffi'
ffi.cdef [[int putenv(const char *asetting);]]
ffi.C.putenv('LANG=ru_RU.utf8') -- поменять ru_RU.utf8 на требуемое значение
```